# Mode to automatically open generated files

Tags: major-mode, flycheck, read-only-mode, auto-revert-mode, code

I'm looking for a mode or hook that automatically opens a generated in read-only and auto-revert-mode mode alongside an associated with a source file. For instance when calling `dmd -vgc-ast` on a `.d`-file or calling the C preprocessor (`cpp`) on a `.c` file.

The mode should be configured via a set of mappings between source file name regexps and generated file regexps.

Comment: How are you calling `dmd` and `cpp`?  `M-x compile`?  Something different?  Please add details.

Comment: I'm calling dmd via flycheck. I haven't thought about cpp yet but probably triggered via a flycheck options popup menu for flycheck in C/C++ mode.